# Even and Odds Max ID VBA

Tags: sql, excel, vba

I have this code in one of my sheets for Excel, that's bringing some data from an SQL Server

```vba
sql = "select max(consecutive) from control_radicados"
rs.Open sql, CN
ActiveSheet.Cells(1, 2).CopyFromRecordset rs
```

What I need to change is that it brings the max even consecutive number, and I haven't found how to do it.

I was trying with a `.IsEven()` after the statement but it didn't worked also with a `.even()` but I don't know if I was using it correctly.

The consecutive comes in as an integer like this

```
Consecutive
50000
50001
50002
50003
50004
50005
50006
50007
```

What I need is that bring the last even consecutive. For example in this case, the max one is 50007 but I need the max even one that will be 50006. Any help would be really really appreciated.

Comment: What RDBMS does this SQL execute against  (sql server, postgres, mysql, oracle, ?) . Can you share sample data from the `control_radicos` table and desired results from that sample data? My guess would be to add something like `WHERE MOD(consecutive, 2) = 0` to the end of that SQL, but without knowing the RDBMS and having a better understanding of what the data looks like and what you are need, it's just a guess.

Comment: Yeah sure, let me edit the post to show the data, thanks

Comment: Still guessing a bit on which SQL engine/RDBMS you are connecting to, but give this a shot: `sql = "select max(consecutive) from control_radicados WHERE MOD(consecutive, 2) = 0"` That should work in most databases. That is saying *"From the `control_radicados` table looking only at records where the value `Consecutive` is even, take the max value"*

Comment: _max even one that will be 50005_ ?? 50005 is odd,

Comment: Thanks man the syntaxes for the engine was a bit different as you said, but the instruction help me a lot. Thanks a lot